# Terminator: keyboard shortcut to flip back-and-forth between two tabs

Tags: shortcut-keys, terminator

I know that one can switch to the next/previous Terminator tab with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

Suppose, however, that I have more than 2 tabs.

I often find myself, for long stretches of time, switching back and forth between *the same two tabs*.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> for this, but it requires me to traverse tabs I'm not interested in at the moment, or, if the two tabs I'm interested in are adjacent, to think about whether I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>.

Therefore, I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut that means "go to the tab that was active before the current one was activated".

If no such shortcut exists, is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm using terminator 0.97 on Debian Jessie derived Bunsen Linux)

My default terminator defines <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> as 'Focus the next terminal' (cycle-next) which seems to cycle through all the split terminals.

<kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Tab</kbd> shows as 'Focus the previous terminal' (cycle-prev)

Will that do what you want ?

(incidently, none of my key combinations with <kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> does anything...)

Comment: It looks like what you have for Ctrl+Tab (resp. Shift+Ctrl+Tab) is equivalent to what I have for Ctrl+PageDown (resp. Ctrl+PageUp).  So, in answer to your question: no, this will not do what I want.